# JpaRepository.getReferenceById sometime return an entity with null values

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm having trouble trying to get an entity via method `getReferenceById` when using Spring Data JPA.

I have two entities like this:

`FileMetadata` 1 - n `FileRawData`

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity(name = "FileMetadata")
@Table(name = "file_metadata")
@DynamicUpdate
public class FileMetadata {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6174939830390750530L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "UUID")
  private UUID id;
  
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "file_name")
  private String fileName;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fileMetadata")
  private List<FileRawData> fileRawData;
}
```

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity(name = "FileRawData")
@Table(name = "file_raw_data")
@DynamicUpdate
public class FileRawData {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 8073845379702147924L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "UUID")
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "raw_data")
  private String rawData;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "file_metadata_id", nullable = false)
  private FileMetadata fileMetadata;
}
```

In my Database I have only one record in file `file_metadata` and I am trying to get this record with method `JpaRepository.getReferenceById` and set to a `FileRawData` entity object (not exist in Database) that I will use in `handle(FileRawData fileRawData)` method.

And in the `handle(FileRawData fileRawData)` method. Some time I can't get the value of the `FileMetadata` entity, even though the value it already exists under DB.

```
  public void handle(FileRawData fileRawData) {
    FileMetadata fileMetadata = fileRawData.getFileMetadata();
    if (fileMetadata.getNumberOfLines() == null) {
      log.info("NumberOfLines is null");
      log.info("{}", fileRawData.getFileMetadata().getId());
      log.info("{}", fileRawData.getFileMetadata().getFileName());
      log.info("{}", fileRawData.getFileMetadata().getNumberOfLines());
    }
```

*All my methods are in the `@Transactional`*

```
2023-03-06 21:35:03.897  INFO 19424 --- [onverter-exec-4] c.t.d.m.e.PlanConvertTaskExecutor        : NumberOfLines is null
2023-03-06 21:35:03.898  INFO 19424 --- [onverter-exec-4] c.t.d.m.e.PlanConvertTaskExecutor        : 96fd27d1-61d6-40cf-b9f9-941664952763
2023-03-06 21:35:03.898  INFO 19424 --- [onverter-exec-4] c.t.d.m.e.PlanConvertTaskExecutor        : \tmp\2023-03-06T14_34_27\tmp_file.csv
2023-03-06 21:35:03.898  INFO 19424 --- [onverter-exec-4] c.t.d.m.e.PlanConvertTaskExecutor        : 40
```

*console log*

### Version:

- spring-boot-starter-parent: 2.7.8
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: 2.7.8
- hibernate-core: 5.6.14.Final

Comment: `getReferenceById` gets an empty object (a proxy) instead of going to the database. So it will have nothing in there. If you want the full object use `findById`.

Comment: @M.Deinum if I'm reading the question correct, the weird part is that the if condition suggests that `getNumberOfLines()` returns `null`, while the log shows it returns `40`. And if this is due to an uninitialized proxy we should get a `LazyInitialisationException`, shouldn't we?

Comment: Please show the code of `getNumberOfLines()`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply  @JensSchauder . Since the `FileRawData` is just a normal entity. So the function `getNumberOfLines()` is just a getter function that was generated by `@Getter` Lombok.

Comment: This problem happens sometimes, but it doesn't throw any exceptions. So my workaround is `findById` instead of `getReferenceById`.